# Verify count_all_results = 1 in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, comparison-operators

I'm trying to accomplish getting the current users session (if it exists) then comparing it to the database, along with a loggedIn value = 1 (meaning loggedIn) and count that a *single* row exists matching this where clause. If that exists, show logged in, else, show login form (shown in `if{}` `else{}` below)

I have a model with a function:

```
function check_if_loggedin(){
    #get user session id from db.
        $sess = $this->session->userdata('session_id');
    #set numerical value of successfully logged in equal 1
        $loggedInSetSuccess = 1;
    #compare session id to match in db (can only have only 1 match)
        $sessionsDbCompare = $this->db->get_where('Client',array('session_id'=>$sess,'loggedIn'=>$loggedInSetSuccess));

    if($sessionsDbCompare->count_all_results() = 1) {
    # User has valid session(valid sessID+loggedIn=0, show welcome
        echo 'Logged in baby';
        # show account pref   
    }
    else{
      # user doesnt have both a valid session and loggedIn is set to 0, show login form
      echo 'login form here';
    }  
}
```

The problem is - `if($sessionsDbCompare->count_all_results() = 1) {` my IDe is warning me, should I be using `count_all_results() == 1` or `count_all_results() === 1` . Sorry this is slightly newbie, I guess I'm a little confused because count_all_results() is a function. (I do understand comparison operators like "1" == "01")

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator while `==` & `===` are comparison operators. In your case you need to compare the two values.

Comment: Okay, cool. But which is better for this case === or == ? and why ?

Comment: You can use either one here as Codeigniter casts the result to `int` before returning. Better to use `===` while comparing numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `==` so the if statement would look like:

```
if($sessionsDbCompare->count_all_results() == 1) { ...
```

You can always use `var_dump($sessionsDbCompare->count_all_results());` or similar to check the value returned...

Comment: Thanks for the var_dump() error checking - will have to keep this in mind. Thanks Salih0vicX!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using this

```
count_all_results() == 1
```

The way you have it is **assigning** 1 to what is left of it

The IDE is also worried that count_all_results()  might return false and 0. That's why it is suggesting the three === but dont worry about that. The two equals will fix it

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if($sessionsDbCompare->count_all_results() = 1) {
```

Should be:

```
if($sessionsDbCompare->count_all_results() == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

you should to use 
$this->db->count_all()
instead of $this->db->count_all_results()